# Are IF..ELSE statements in a View frowned upon in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know that you want to keep logic out of your views. I can elimate most loops by using DisplayFor/EditorFor and passing IEnumerables to the view.

What about IF statements? should they be avoided completely in views? used sparingly? as a last resort?

Say you wanted to show hide an element based on a User role...How would u go about doing this without an IF statement...a completely seperate view perhaps?

Just trying to get an idea of best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be consistent, and keep in mind the purpose of the view - to produce your HTML. Toward that end, certainly you will need some `if` constructs here or there. I think some people are suggesting you stick to some pie-in-the-sky, ultra-nitpicky purism here at the expense of usable, functional, well-defined code.

Comment: I'd ask the inverse question, actually. Why in the world wouldn't I put an if statement in my view? Sometimes what is being displayed is conditioned on the state of the model.

Comment: @Serge - haha... thanks :) @mcl - I agree. It's a rare view, aside from partials or extremely simple ones, that doesn't have *some* sort of need to *decide what HTML to produce* based on some condition of the Model. What some people suggested below actually **breaks the concept of separation of concerns** :: It specifically asks the Model or Controller to handle how to display things.

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing wrong with using `if`s in your views, as long as you don't end up putting backend logic in them.

Answer (score 3):

Rob Conery has a rule of thumb that states ["if there's and IF, make a helper"](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-avoiding-tag-soup/). Personally, I would say "use sparingly". I avoid it as much as possible because it makes things more difficult to unit test.

For the situation where you want to hide elements based on user roles: For simple scenarios, I would probably put the check directly in the view.  Usually I try to still make these more terse and testable, though.  So instead of:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")
{
    // Show admin stuff
}
```

I would do something like:

```
@if (Model.UserIsAdmin)
{
    // Show admin stuff
}
```

On the other hand, if these kinds of checks started getting speckled all over your views, I'd probably create the elements conditionally in the viewmodel first, and then just display what's been built.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically every View should display whats passed in ViewModel. If ViewModel is not enough, then I would look for a way of improving the ViewModel creation itself, not the View's logic.

All conditionals CAN be evaluated upon ViewModel creation.

Of course, It all depends on how much custom-logic in View does Your project organization tolerates.

Answer (score 0):

If / else can be used sparingly, in my opinion, but for the example you mention, hide an element based on role - the if check should definitely not be in the view. Write extensions and helpers where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think is the better to avoid if in the view, You should avoid business(Model) or application(Controller) logic in the view
in your example you can create different Partial View for display some think depend on user role and in the Controller put the logic for what view you need to show

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to hide element by "if" in the view, but in code you must disable function (method), which is activated by hidden element.

Comment: BTW, I wanted say, that if must be simplistic: if (model.IsButtonOkVisible) //show button.